# Creating additional stores on same server in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore

I'm very new to Magento, so it's all so confusing.

How can i make a multistore domain specific store with diffrent prices, but same inventory?

eg. b2b.domain.com for wholesalecustomers, and domain.com for regular customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently created multiple domain with single Magento 2 installation. Using this guide you will able to create multiple website as well as multiple store. Please read it once and you will get all the required solutions.
[Read more](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-run.html)